# Boot CD for partitioning hard drives?

Tags: partition

I am in an odd situation where Backup Exec system recovery won't talk to a new disk because it doesn't like the MBR or partition table. The built in system recovery partition tools are insufficient.

So, is there a bootable CD that has a great partition manager, volume creator?

This will ultimately be an NTFS volume.

Comment: You've clearly made no attempt to do any research for yourself. This topic has come up numerous times on this site alone.

Comment: The above is not true. I did a fair amount of googling before posting this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) LiveCD.

GParted enables you to easily manage your disk partitions:

- Create partition tables, (e.g., msdos or gpt)
- Create, move, copy, resize, check, label, set new UUID, and delete partitions
- Enable and disable partition flags, (e.g., boot or hidden)
- Align partitions to mebibyte (MiB) or traditional cylinder boundaries
- Attempt data rescue from lost partitions

Comment: gparted rocks. Booted off CD, was able to create partition, format as ntfs, then system recovery was able to restore to it A OK.  Thanks!  (Why the heck they closed this thread is beyond me!)

Answer (score 0):

GParted is a great tool. However this may not solve your problem trying to restore an MS backup image.

I had a similar issue a few months ago using an MS backup image to restore my WIN 7 Pro 64 bit to a different disk (shuffling disks around to change Raid set-up). The restore would never let me try to partition and restore to the disk I wanted to. 
1.) Initially it wanted to restore to location where it was backed up from - I removed partition. No luck.
2.) Used install CD and did a quick minimal install on target disk. MS restore liked this and restored over the newly installed image AND re-sized the partition to the size originally backed up.

Spent 2 frustrating days to learn this "quirk" in MS Backup/Restore.

BTW - disks are GPT and I am using UEFI boot. No idea if the same issue exists with MBR disks and BIOS boot.

Good luck